# Считывание атрибута из html тега с помощью Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, html, selenium

```
<input id="" name="" maxlength="100" readonly="" title="root@ru.stackoverflow.com">
```

есть такой тег, найти его не проблема.
но как средствами selenium вытянуть текст из атрибута title в переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

виноват, в итоге нашел ответ на свой вопрос. причем в течение двух минут после его публикации.

```
WebElement titleread = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
String lr = loginread.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(lr); // для проверки
```

Comment: не забудьте отметить свой ответ как принятый